# Deference of a possibly null reference

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

```
public async Task<User> GetUserByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return await myAppDbContext.tbl_User.FindAsync(id);
    }
```

myAppDbContext is not null here, Possible null reference return.

Constructor :

```
private readonly MyAppDbContext myAppDbContext;

    public UserRepository(MyAppDbContext myAppDbContext)
    {
        this.myAppDbContext = myAppDbContext;
    }
```

How do we get rid of this warning.
I tried adding question mark after MyAppDbContext?.
Googled, but not many helpful answers.

Comment: isnt it related to tbl_User ?

Comment: What if Find doesn't (find anything)? With that method signature of `Task<User>` you've said "there definitely will be a non null User come back from GetUserByIdAsync", but Find on a non existing  ID will result in null User..

Comment: Signature needs to be `public async Task<User?> GetUserByIdAsync(int id)` (assuming you have `Nullable` set to enable null reference types).

Comment: @sellotape or guard against null in the method if you don't want to kick the can down the road

Comment: _`await myAppDbContext.tbl_User.FindAsync(id);`_ Don't do "useless" awaits when you can return the task directly.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen  not sure I'd recommend such in an off the cuff comment- worth linking to a more involved discussion about it eg https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html

Comment: @CaiusJard sounds like a better plan, didn't took enough time for it.